# Error 400 with ajax request

Tags: javascript, ajax, request

I am new to web development, and I guess that it is a basic issue, but I couldn't find a solution on the internet.

To start, what I am trying to do is to have a script, loaded on a webpage using TamperMonkey, download a xml file located on a php server.

The process worked perfectly when I tested it on localhost (using MAMP), but then I put it on a 000webhost server, and it's not working, I get an Error 400 Bad request in the ajax response. I also tried on other web hosting services and I get the same error.

On the other hand, the request works perfectly on the 000webhost server when I'm just sending it though my google chrome searchbar. Also, the url to which it is sent is well formed, as when I console.log it, and then click the link, it does what it should.

I am using the GM_xmlhttpRequest method. Here is the code :

```
let url = some_correct_url;
GM_xmlhttpRequest({
        methode: "GET",
        url: url,
        headers: {
            "Accept": "text/xml"
        },
        onload: function(response){
            var r= null;
            if (!response.responseXML){
                r= new DOMParser().parseFromString(response.responseXML, "text/xml");
            }
            r= response.responseXML;
            console.log(r);
            console.log(response.responseText);
            });
        });
```

Comment: You have a typo in your request body: *mehtode* should be *method*

Comment: that was it thank you :)

Comment: damn frogs :p haha

Comment: spending so much time because of this f... huh cute little "e" was a lot of fun^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in your request body.

Typo: `methodE: "GET"`

Please correct the typo so it reads `method: "GET"` and let us know the results.

Comment: Oh my god that was it, thanks a lot ^^
But why would it work on localhost then ?

Comment: Awesome, glad to hear it! I'm not sure how sending the request from your local machine could've worked if the request contained the typo. The response returned by the remote host should be the same regardless of the machine it was sent from.

By the way, I'd suggest checking out the program Postman if you are troubleshooting or testing some sort of endpoint, it can really come in handy.

Comment: Ok thanks, I will have a look into it. It is not easy to see where problems are coming from when you begin learning web development^^